# Problem creating a container Panel in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am new to ExtJS and I want to create a container Panel for my buttons in ExtJS, all i managed to do so far is to try to add a simple button in my class like so :

```
    Ext.define('MyClass.view.buttons', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
  
    alias: 'widget.MyClass',


    controller: 'MyClass',
    requires: [
      
       'MyClass.view.Main',

    ],
    items   : [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text : 'My Button'
        }
    ]

});
```

Which doesn't display nothing too (with no reported errors in the console).
Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

You can user `handler` or `listeners` property to set click handler. My code was just for reference and rendering element to body will of course render it on page and not inside another element. Take a look at this updated example, where I have used `xtype` property of my defined component to use it inside another custom component.

```
Ext.define('MyClass.view.buttons', {
  extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
  alias: 'widget.MyClass',
  xtype: 'myclass',
  items: [{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Child Button Button',
    handler: function() {
        alert('You clicked the button!');
    }
  }]
});

Ext.define('MyClass.view.anotherButtons', {
  extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
  alias: 'widget.MyAnotherClass',
  items: [{
    xtype: 'myclass'
  }, {
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Parent Container Button'
  }]
});

Ext.create('MyClass.view.anotherButtons', {
  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
  width: 400,
  height: 300,
});
```

```js
Ext.define('MyClass.view.buttons', {
  extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
  alias: 'widget.MyClass',
  items: [{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'My Button'
  }]
});
Ext.create('MyClass.view.buttons', {
  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
  width: 400,
  height: 300,
});
```

Comment: now the buttons shows on every window, which i don't want, i want it only on the current component.

Comment: Also how to add a listener on this button ?

Comment: @user1319236 check out my updated and I would recommend you to read documentation bit more.

Comment: Actually the buttons still show on the outmost UI and on the concernet component. so the bad behaviour is still there. but thanks for the listener

Comment: @user1319236 unless I will have reproducible code, it is hard for me to imagine changes required, most likely its some missing property configuration.

Comment: thanks also how to style the added buttons ? position and styling ? thanks !

Comment: always begin with documentation, there is `style` property on button definition use that: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html